# Show Pdf using p:media in Primfaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, media

I want to view a pdf file that is stored as a `blob` in my Oracle Database. I'm using a `<p:media/>` in the `xhml` , and `StreamedContent` in the backing bean.

Here is `xhtml`

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

 <p:outputPanel id="outputPanelDialogShowPdf">

    <div style="text-align: center">
        <p:media value="#{bean.media}" width="600px" height="300px" player="pdf" />
    </div>

    <p:spacer height="1px" />
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <p:commandButton value="#{msgs.button_cancel}" icon="ui-icon-cancel" oncomplete="dialogShowPdf.hide();" 
                         action="#{bean[cancelAction]}" immediate="true" />
    </div>
</p:outputPanel>
```

And here is the action button (which is part of data table) which calls the action bean

```
    <p:commandButton value="Show PDF"
                              update=":formMediaDataDialogShowPdf:outputPanelDialogShowPdf" 
                              oncomplete="PF('dialogShowPdf').show()" 
                              action="#{ bean.showPdfAction }" rendered="#{ mediaData.mediaType == 'application/pdf'}"> 
                 <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{mediaData}" target="#{bean.selectedMediaData}" />
            </p:commandButton>
```

And this is the action in the bean

```
public void showPdfAction(){

    if (null != selectedMediaData) { 
        media = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(selectedMediaData.getMediaData()),"application/pdf");   
    }
}
```

The problem is that the media is not being displayed even though the action in the bean runs without errors, and the `media` property in the bean is being properly initialized.

Can anyone provide some help for that

Comment: @kukeltje Do you have a thought retarding the code?

Comment: Yes I read, but does that have anything to do with what I'm asking ? just asking.

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje .. updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of research, I found a solution that worked quite well with me.

I have updated the action in the bean as follows

```
if (null != selectedMediaData) { 
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);

    session.setAttribute("pdfBytesArray", selectedMediaData.getMediaData());
}
```

Now as I'm passing `pdfBytesArray` as a session attribute, I've created a servlet where I can get this attribute from the session and then process the byte array then writing it to response stream with a content type of `application/pdf`

```
public class PdfPreviewServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    byte[] pdfBytesArray = (byte[]) request.getSession().getAttribute("pdfBytesArray");
    request.getSession().removeAttribute("pdfBytesArray");
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(pdfBytesArray.length);
    response.getOutputStream().write(pdfBytesArray);
} }
```

Then annotated the servlet with `@WebServlet("/pdfPreviewServlet")`

Then changed `<p:media/>` to `<p:media value="/pdfPreviewServlet" player="pdf"/>`